# Load more li's in ul - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project where I have reviews and want to display first 3 and when you press load more it should load three more reviews. I am not good at JQuery and found this code, seemed to work first, but it's showing all my results at once and the load more doesn't really do the trick. (I've skipped the show less part, unless someone can help me fix it)

HTML:

```
    <ul id="results">
        <li>...CONTENT1...</li>
        <li>...CONTENT2...</li>
        <li>...CONTENT3...</li>
    </ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(window).load(function(){
        $(document).ready(function () {
            size_li = $("#results li").size();
            x=3;
            $('#results li:lt('+x+')').show();
            $('#loadMore').click(function () {
                x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
                $('#results li:lt('+x+')').show();
                 $('#showLess').show();
                if(x == size_li){
                    $('#loadMore').hide();
                }
            });
            $('#showLess').click(function () {
                x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
                $('#results li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
                $('#loadMore').show();
                 $('#showLess').show();
                if(x == 3){
                    $('#showLess').hide();
                }
            });
        });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Are your list items past the third starting as hidden? (`style="display: none"`)

Comment: Not really, guess it should be like that? :)

Comment: `size()` is deprecated, use `length` property instead `var size_li = $("#results li").length`

Answer (score 1):

you need to hide them initially,

```
#results li {display:none;}
```